# GraphicsMagick TTF Font Performance

Tags: c++, performance, imagemagick, truetype, graphicsmagick

I am using GraphicsMagick in a C++ library in order to create rasterized output, which mainly consists out of text.

I am doing something like this:

```
void gfx_writer::add_text(Magick::Image& img) const
{
    using namespace Magick;
    const unsigned x = // just a position;
    const unsigned y_title =  // just a position;
    const unsigned y_heading =  // just a position;
    const unsigned y_value =  // just a position;

    img.strokeColor("transparent");
    img.fillColor("black");

    img.font(font_title_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_title_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{static_cast<double>(x), static_cast<double>(y_title), "a text"});

    img.font(font_heading_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_heading_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{static_cast<double>(x), static_cast<double>(y_heading), "another text"});

    img.font(font_value_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_value_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{static_cast<double>(x), static_cast<double>(y_value), "third text"});
}
```

Whereas `font_title_`, `font_heading_` and `font_value_` are paths to the TTF files.

This is done more than once and I experience rather bad performance. When I have a look at what happens using Sysinternals Process Monitor I see that the TTF files are read over and over again. So my questions are:

- are my observations correct, that the TTF files are read each time `img.font(...)` is called?
- is there a way to somehow cache the font using GraphicsMagick OR to provided something else than just the path to the TTF file?
- any other thing I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

**Note: This answer uses ImageMagick's `Magick++` library, and may have minor portability issues with GraphicsMagick, but the underlying solution is the same.**

> are my observations correct, that the TTF files are read each time img.font(...) is called?

Yes, the TTF font is reloaded each time. One option is to install the fonts in the system, and call the font-family constructor.

```cpp
DrawableFont ( const std::string &family_,
               StyleType style_,
               const unsigned long weight_,
               StretchType stretch_ );
```

Most systems have some sort of font caching system that would allow quicker access, but not really noticeable on modern hardware.

> any other thing I am missing?

Try building a graphical context, and only call `Magick::Image.draw` once. Remember that the `Drawable...` calls are only wrapping MVG statements, and creating a `std::list<Drawable>` allows you to build complex vectors. Only when the `draw` method consumes the draw commands is when the TTF will be loaded, so its key to prepare all the drawing commands ahead of time.

Let's start by rewriting the code you provided (and I'm taking a degree of liberty here).

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

const char * font_title_ = "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf";
const char * font_heading_ = "fonts/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf";
const char * font_value_ = "fonts/sansation.ttf";
double font_size_title_ = 32;
double font_size_heading_ = 24;
double font_size_value_ = 16;

void gfx_writer_add_text(Magick::Image& img)
{
    using namespace Magick;
    double x = 10.0;
    double y_title = 10;
    double y_heading = 20.0;
    double y_value =  30.0;

    img.strokeColor("transparent");
    img.fillColor("black");

    img.font(font_title_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_title_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{x, y_title, "a text"});

    img.font(font_heading_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_heading_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{x, y_heading, "another text"});

    img.font(font_value_);
    img.fontPointsize(font_size_value_);
    img.draw(DrawableText{x, y_value, "third text"});
}

int main()
{
    Magick::Image img("wizard:");
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    img.write("output.png");
}
```

I can compile and benchmark the run time. I get the following times:

```
$ time ./original.o 
real    0m5.061s
user    0m0.094s
sys     0m0.029s
```

Refactoring the code to use a drawing context, and only call `Magick::Image.draw` once.

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <list>

const char * font_title_ = "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf";
const char * font_heading_ = "fonts/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf";
const char * font_value_ = "fonts/sansation.ttf";
double font_size_title_ = 32;
double font_size_heading_ = 24;
double font_size_value_ = 16;

void gfx_writer_add_text(Magick::Image& img)
{
    using namespace Magick;
    double x = 10.0;
    double y_title = 10;
    double y_heading = 20.0;
    double y_value =  30.0;

    std::list<Drawable> ctx;
    ctx.push_back(DrawableStrokeColor("transparent"));
    ctx.push_back(DrawableFillColor("black"));
    /* TITLE */
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePushGraphicContext());
    ctx.push_back(DrawableFont(font_title_);
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePointSize(font_size_title_));
    ctx.push_back(DrawableText{x, y_title, "a text"});
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePopGraphicContext());
    /* HEADING */
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePushGraphicContext());
    ctx.push_back(DrawableFont(font_heading_));
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePointSize(font_size_heading_));
    ctx.push_back(DrawableText{x, y_heading, "another text"});
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePopGraphicContext());
    /* Value */
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePushGraphicContext());
    ctx.push_back(DrawableFont(font_value_));
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePointSize(font_size_value_));
    ctx.push_back(DrawableText{x, y_value, "third text"});
    ctx.push_back(DrawablePopGraphicContext());
    img.draw(ctx);
}

int main()
{
    Magick::Image img("wizard:");
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    gfx_writer_add_text(img);
    img.write("output2.png");
}
```

And the benchmark times are slightly better.

```
$ time ./with_context.o
real    0m0.106s
user    0m0.090s
sys     0m0.012s
```

> This is done more than once and I experience rather bad performance.

Worth taking a step back, and asking: *"How can a refactor my solution to only draw at the last possible moment?"*.

Comment: Collecting the drawables was a good hint. I switched code and experimented always having a look at execution times and the number of ttf file access (I count "CloseFile" in Process Monitor. 

What I noticed was, that a single DrawableText caused TTF accesses (based on CloseFile count). So unfortunately it looks like GraphicsMagick re-reads the TTF file not matter if I use the Magick++ api with multiple draw calls or if I collected the Drawables.

I do have a few DrawableTexts(lets say about 30-40). I also need to access font metrics which seem to cause a lot more TTF reads.

Comment: Sadly problem persists for me.

Not sure if this old thread is relevant/applicable for the current GraphicsMagick version as well, but still sounds familiar. https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6171&sid=c4511a68ffad7148f40f947336ef1d7a&start=15

Comment: BTW: what are the benefits of using DrawablePushGraphicContext and DrawablePopGraphicContext?

Comment: And finally tested using installed fonts

`ctx_headings.push_back(DrawableFont("Arial"));`

Did not improved situation neither.

Comment: Might be worth checking out what [MVG](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php) drawing contexts looks like. The `Drawable...` methods just collect a list of MVG instructions, and in no way interact with the file system -- at least not into they are digested by the final draw command. The push/pop is a classic stack operation to manage various drawing states.

Comment: Thanks for the MVG link, just checked it. It helps and I got the stack operations, however, I was not certain if it was used as a sort of "scope" for the given draw options (or "states" as you wrote).

Yes, sure I get what you mean by that the MVG instructions do not interact with the file system. I am only saying that there are many TTF file access when all the Drawables are passed to the image in order to render them. That said, it appears to me, that we are not able to optimize this.

I am thinking about switching from GraphicsMagick to SFML or Cairo, but I haven't compared/tested yet.

Comment: Basically this answer did not solve my issue, but it gave useful hints and I appreciate the effort. Thus bounty goes to emcconville.